# What are the alternatives for <first> in NAnt?

Tags: ant, nant

In Ant you can use the following script:

```
 <first id="first">
        <fileset dir="dir.zips" includes="**/a.zip" />
 </first>
 <echo message="${toString:first}" />
```

to get the first file from the filelist.

Is there any alternative for the same in NAnt. `<First>` is not a valid task in NAnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alterative, though it is not efficient

```
<property name="iter" value="0" overwrite="true"/>
<property name="first" value="" overwrite="true"/>
<foreach item="file" property="filename" in"src\build">
    <do>
        <if test="${iter == '0'}">
            <property name="first" value="${filename}" overwrite="true"/>
        </if>
    <do>
    <property name = "iter" value="${int::parse(iter) + 1}"/>
</foreach>
```

Since the loop won't break after first iteration, I have decided to create a custom task.